# Android Spinner: Change item name?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Is it possible to change the displayed name of a spinner-item without changing the actual value of the item?

For example, I'm currently adding some website-links from a `List` to the spinner and instead of showing the actual link, I want the spinner to just show a description of that link. Is that possible?

Or do I have to change the spinner, that i'm not adding the actual website-link as an item, but the description instead and then select the link programmatically depending on which description was selected?

Hope you understand what i'm trying to do here...

Comment: Can make your own adapter that takes name-value pairs as content. Use the name for display and the value as link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround but will suit this situation. on

you can have a hashmap(it will have mapped info for your links and desc) store link of description and call like this

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    navigatetoLink(Hashmap.get( parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)));
}
```